# Filtering results by comparing a float value

Tags: mysql, sql

My query takes results from a table `gig` and average of customers stars given to that specific gig. I want to take the averages of stars greater than 3.

However, average values are like `4.00000`, `3.90000`, `2.8000000`. Its OK, but I want to get the result for only results where the average value is more than `3.0`.

But the query ends with an error.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT 
    gig.* ,
    (SELECT AVG(order_customer_stars)
     FROM orders
     WHERE orders.gig_id = gig.gig_id) AS star_average
FROM gig 
WHERE star_average > 3
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Which error ? Can you show us database structure of both involved tables ?

Comment: @PHPnoob One table is "gig", Another table is "Orders". One Gig Many Orders. On "Orders" table, there is gig_id and a column order_customer_stars (1-5) where customer can give stars to a gig order. In my query i m taking average of stars for gig from orders table.

Comment: Please provide more details by editing your question. As @PHPnoob wrote, a database structure diagram (showing the related tables) and a detailed error message is needed to help you.

Comment: @PHPnoob i got my solution from Gordon' Answer below. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL extends the having clause to do what you want:

```
SELECT gig.* ,
       (SELECT AVG(order_customer_stars)
        FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.gig_id = gig.gig_id
       ) AS star_average
FROM gig 
HAVING star_average > 3;
```

In other databases, you would use a CTE, subquery, or lateral join.

Comment: How can I have both HAVING and WHERE clause for example if I want gig_price greater than 50 from gig table shoukd I use `WHERE gig_price>50 HAVING star_average>3` or `HAVING gig_price>50 AND star_average>3` ???

Comment: @AbubakrCh . . . You can have both a `WHERE` and a `HAVING` clause.